# Custom email notification to different email ids Magento

Tags: php, html, magento

I am using magento `1.7`. I have custom files in which when the order is placed, the order form should be send to different email id's.

Now I am able to send the mails to different email id's and getting shipping and billing details in the mail but I am not getting ordered items.I am using following code. But its displays nothing.

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

How would I go with it?
 
Link referred : http://www.atwix.com/magento/emails-for-custom-events/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the observer file did you used the template variable:

```
$emailTemplateVariables['order'] = $order;
```